# System.Drawing support with lambda container images

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, openxml-powertools

I was trying to add System.Drawing library inside a lambda function using container image. Followed the AWS documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-5-aws-lambda-support-with-container-images/)

Added

```
RUN yum install -y amazon-linux-extras 
RUN amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
RUN yum install -y libgdiplus
```

Inside the `Dockerfile`.

while calling the lambda i am getting an error

**System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Drawing.Common is not supported on non-Windows platforms. See https://aka.ms/systemdrawingnonwindows for more information.**

Comment: I don't see a question here.  But as the error mention indicates, System.Drawing isn't supported on non-Windows platforms.  Lambda is a non-Windows platform, so unfortunately you can not use the System.Drawing library in a Lambda function.

I believe Microsoft is working on something to get System.Drawing (or a new equivalent) to work cross plat.

Comment: hi @PhilipPittle i was able to fix the issue. I've Downgraded the version of system.drawing.common package from 6.0.0 to 4.7.0 and now is working .

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to downgrade the package from v6.0.0. In .NET 6 you can fix the issue by adding this line to your startup code (before calling any GDI-dependent code):

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport", true);
```

But please note that this will not work in v7.0.0 and above. Unix support has already been removed from the 7.0.0-preview.* versions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the version of **System.Drawing.Common** package I am using. I've downgraded the package from 6.0.0 to 4.7.0 and the error went away.